# Ebay Inventory API "Get Inventory Item " 404 Not Found

Tags: ebay-api

When I am tryping to request on ebay inventory API using API Exploler. I am geting the Call Respond Statud code 404.

and Following error message. can anyone help me to solve the issue

```
{"errors": [
 {
  "errorId": 25710,
  "domain": "API_INVENTORY",
  "subdomain": "Selling",
  "category": "REQUEST",
  "message": "We didn't find the entity you are requesting. Please verify the request"
} ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

That message means there is an issue either with the item, or the SKU. Maybe you typed the SKU incorrectly. Maybe you're looking in the account of the wrong user.

But my guess... The SKU was of an item that wasn't created with the API, and was instead created manually using eBay's front end. That command only works on items also created by similar commands.

Comment: Thanks @jonathon for you advice. But this message come from the ebay API Exploer and the Item SKU I provide that also from exam sample SKU. Do you have any idea how can get inventory item from the api request

Comment: Yes, I know where the message came from.

This call calls an item from your account, with that SKU. You're getting that error message because no such item exists. Or if it does, the item is configured wrong.